# How do I dynamically get the value of an element from an array of elements?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 3 checkboxes. I'm trying to the value of whichever checkbox is clicked on. I'm able to get the value of a hardcoded checkbox index (checkbox[0] for example), but I can't get the value of checkbox[i] with vanilla JS.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var listType = document.getElementById('ListType');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      var inputByIndex = checkboxes[0].value; //I can get the value of the first element, but I can't get the value of whichever checkbox is checked. checkbox[i] doesn't work.
      listType.classList.add(inputByIndex);
      var spanType = document.getElementById("type");
      spanType.innerText = inputByIndex;

    });
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 20px;
}

#ListType.basiclist {
  color: red;
}

#ListType.accordionlist {
  color: blue;
}

#ListType.internalonly {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<form id="ListTypes">
  <label for "basicList"><input type="checkbox" id="basicList" class="checkbox" name="basicList" value="basiclist"/>Basic List</label>
  <label for "accordionList"><input type="checkbox" id="accordionList" class="checkbox" name="accordionList" value="accordionlist"/>Accordion List</label>
  <label for "internalOnly"><input type="checkbox" id="internalOnly" class="checkbox" name="internalOnly" value="internalonly" />Internal Use Only</label>
</form>

<div id="ListType">
  List Type: <span id="type"></span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimberwarden/jLzq8d9o/88/)

Comment: Why the downgrades? I searched hard to find the answer myself and tried to word and format my question very carefully.

Comment: The question is written ok. I think someone feels a solution was easy to find - don't take it personally

Comment: And here is an upvote for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` loop, use `let` instead of `var` to make it work:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var listType = document.getElementById('ListType');
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      var inputByIndex = checkboxes[i].value; //I can get the value of the first element, but I can't get the value of whichever checkbox is checked. checkbox[i] doesn't work.
      listType.classList.add(inputByIndex);
      var spanType = document.getElementById("type");
      spanType.innerText = inputByIndex;

    });
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 20px;
}

#ListType.basiclist {
  color: red;
}

#ListType.accordionlist {
  color: blue;
}

#ListType.internalonly {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<form id="ListTypes">
  <label for "basicList"><input type="checkbox" id="basicList" class="checkbox" name="basicList" value="basiclist"/>Basic List</label>
  <label for "accordionList"><input type="checkbox" id="accordionList" class="checkbox" name="accordionList" value="accordionlist"/>Accordion List</label>
  <label for "internalOnly"><input type="checkbox" id="internalOnly" class="checkbox" name="internalOnly" value="internalonly" />Internal Use Only</label>
</form>

<div id="ListType">
  List Type: <span id="type"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to add event listeners to each element. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69815857/295783) for something more elegant

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to access the element on which event has occurred.

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var listType = document.getElementById('ListType');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var inputByIndex = event.currentTarget.value;
      listType.classList.add(inputByIndex);
      var spanType = document.getElementById("type");
      spanType.innerText = inputByIndex;

    });
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 20px;
}

#ListType.basiclist {
  color: red;
}

#ListType.accordionlist {
  color: blue;
}

#ListType.internalonly {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<form id="ListTypes">
  <label for "basicList"><input type="checkbox" id="basicList" class="checkbox" name="basicList" value="basiclist"/>Basic List</label>
  <label for "accordionList"><input type="checkbox" id="accordionList" class="checkbox" name="accordionList" value="accordionlist"/>Accordion List</label>
  <label for "internalOnly"><input type="checkbox" id="internalOnly" class="checkbox" name="internalOnly" value="internalonly" />Internal Use Only</label>
</form>

<div id="ListType">
  List Type: <span id="type"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate

You need to think of the CSS for more than one listType color or use a set of radio buttons

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('ListTypes').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.type && tgt.type === 'checkbox') { 
      const values = [...tgt.form.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked")].map(chk => chk.value);
      document.getElementById("type").textContent = values.join(", ")
      document.getElementById("ListType").classList.add(...values);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 20px;
}

#ListType.basiclist {
  color: red;
}

#ListType.accordionlist {
  color: blue;
}

#ListType.internalonly {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<form id="ListTypes">
  <label for "basicList"><input type="checkbox" id="basicList" class="checkbox" name="basicList" value="basiclist"/>Basic List</label>
  <label for "accordionList"><input type="checkbox" id="accordionList" class="checkbox" name="accordionList" value="accordionlist"/>Accordion List</label>
  <label for "internalOnly"><input type="checkbox" id="internalOnly" class="checkbox" name="internalOnly" value="internalonly" />Internal Use Only</label>
</form>

<div id="ListType">
  List Type: <span id="type"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `checkboxes` list doesn't exist within the closure of the `onclick` funcion. Instead use `this.value`.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxkznb70/1/)

Comment: On the contrary, the `checkboxes` list does exist within the closure of the `onclick` function. It's the index that causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select them all using the method you would like (I used [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) & ) and do an iteration over them (I used [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

This is the most simple function you can ever find.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

checkboxes.forEach(singleCheckbox => {
  singleCheckbox.addEventListener('click', () => alert(singleCheckbox.id))
});
```

```html
<label for="first">First<input type="checkbox" id="first"/></label>
<label for="second">Second<input type="checkbox" id="second"/></label>
<label for="third">Third<input type="checkbox" id="third"/></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make clear what was actually the problem with your code...

At the time you `click` handler will be fired the `for` loop will end its work and thus, the value of `i` will become exactly `checkboxes.length`, and of course, there is no checkbox with such an index, because the last of them has index `(checkboxes.length - 1)`. So the reason is that the code inside of the handler is executed **after** `for` loop ends its work.

The solutions were already provided by other users.